# Python: requests.get gets the wrong html file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from https://essentials.swissdox.ch, which only works with VPN. So what I did is, I generated a URL with my query parameters and tried to get the correspondent html file. The problem is, that although the link works, Python gives me the html file of the starting page of https://essentials.swissdox.ch. I really appreciate any help!

Example:
I want the html file of the following url: https://essentials.swissdox.ch/View/log/index.jsp#&search=true&filter_de=la&sortorder=pubDateTime%20desc&formdata=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_mltid%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_sc%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22swissdox%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_query%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22lissabon%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22filter_de%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22de%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_exact%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22true%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22dateDropdown%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_pubDate_lower%22%2C%22value%22%3A%222020-02-04%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_pubDate_upper%22%2C%22value%22%3A%222020-02-04%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_tiall%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_source%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_author%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D

Instead I get the html file of this page: https://essentials.swissdox.ch/View/log/index.jsp?reset=true

Here is what I have so far:

```
#Set keywords for URL
keyword_queries = ['lissabon']
startdate = "2007-01-01"
enddate = "2007-01-01"

#Encode  and hit URL
for keyword in keyword_queries:
    html_keyword= urllib.parse.quote_plus(keyword)
    URL = "https://essentials.swissdox.ch/View/log/index.jsp#&search=true&sortorder=pubDateTime%20desc&formdata=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_mltid%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_sc%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22swissdox%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_query%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22" + html_keyword + "%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_exact%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22true%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22dateDropdown%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22-1%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_pubDate_lower%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22" + startdate + "%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_pubDate_upper%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22" + enddate + "%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_tiall%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_source%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22SEARCH_author%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D"
    weburl  = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    
    #Hit the url
    ua = UserAgent()
    page = requests.get(URL, {"User-Agent": ua.random})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('div', class_='documentlist')
    print(page.content)
```

Comment: Make sure whether the links need authentication. If auth details not provided it will redirect to login/sign up sort of page

Comment: the links don't need any login credentials, only my VPN

Comment: Are you sure the site doesn't depend on cookies?  requests follows redirects, so it's likely that the other end is sending back a "redirect" to your original request, either because the URL was badly formed or it insisted upon a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used '#' instead of '?' in your url. Usually '?' will be used to start the query parameters, which are specified with '=' between key-value pairs.

Using '#' means to jump to a specific section in the page, in this case https://essentials.swissdox.ch/View/log/index.jsp which is what you are getting as response. Changing '#' to '?' seems to throw an error about invalid characters on the original URL. Make sure you use valid characters while [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the query parameters.

[Wiki - URL Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)

Comment: The url that I posted is the one I get, when I enter my keywords on the website and press search. So it should be correct. Any other ideas why this isn't working?  Could it be that it insisted upon a cookie, and if yes, is there a way to fix that in Python?

Comment: It could be the case that cookies are required. You can get the cookie value from your browser developer console and use it with [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) (Warning: Don't share your cookie with others)